# Compile three executables in one makefile

Tags: makefile, design-patterns

I have the following makefile:

```
prog1: prog1.c

       gcc -o prog1.exe prog1.c

prog2: prog2.c

       gcc -o prog2.exe prog2.c

prog3: prog3.c

       gcc -o prog3.exe prog3.c
```

This are demo files in a demo directory which I want to compile in one makefile.

How can I use patterns to shorten this?

e.g. in this direction:

```
    progs= prog1 prog2 prog3

    all: ($progs)

%.exe: %.c

      gcc .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
%.exe: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

Comment: Make knows how to do this, and its built-in rules understand additional compiler and linker arguments, as well as necessary libraries if specified.

Comment: @Novelocrat: sure it does, but the OP specifically asked how to use patterns to shorten his solution.

Comment: The way to shorten this is to use Make's built-in patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Make knows how to build executables from source files. You should be able to write the entire makefile as

```
progs := prog1 prog2 prog3
all: $(progs)
```

If you need to specify what C compiler to use, just add a line reading

```
CC := gcc
```

If you need to pass your compiler additional flags, put them in the `CFLAGS` variable.

**EDIT:** To address the desire for a file named `foo.exe`, you can either move it after it's built:

```
%.exe: %
            mv $< $@
```

Or, if you know you're using the GNU toolchain, you can tell the linker to give you that prefix:

```
LDFLAGS := --force-exe-suffix
```

Unfortunately, GNU Make doesn't seem to offer a standard variable for 'the suffix/extension on built executables'

Comment: +1, but notice that Georg's makefile actually produces e.g. `prog1.exe`, not `prog1`.

Comment: OK, so a rule reading
%.exe: %
    mv $< $@
would be the appropriate response, without looking at the Make docs. I bet there's a builtin variable that one can set for 'executable suffix'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your posts! I found that I have to add a rule to make it work. Also I added touch to be able to repeat the makefile.

```
progs = prog1 prog2 prog3

all: run_touch $(progs)

run_touch:

    touch *.cpp

%:%.cpp

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```